# Finite set of vectors, finding the value behind each vector into a list

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I am a computer science student and was wondering if there was a mathematical formula for finding a specific vector at a coordinate if you could imagine A...Z vectors layered behind one another in subsequent or linear order.

Example
`A = { 1, 2, 3 }`
`B = { 4, 5, 6 }`
`... and so on until Z`

Finding for example, given the input question of a vector position `A[0]` would provide the answers 1, 4, ... until Z's value. `A[2]` would provide 3, 6... And so on.

Is it possible to find a formula for this? What type of mathematics is this? Any information would be helpful to point me in a direction to learn.

Sorry if anything is is-labled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is majorly an implementation question depending on which language you are using - not a maths question

Use a matrix to represent the vectors, where each row is a the vector. So if you have $N$ vectors of dimension 3, you are constructing a $N \times 3$ matrix, let's call this $M$

Now, you just transpose this matrix - hence what used to be the columns are now the rows - and each column was what you are after. Now you can extract each row trivially

Now for the actual transpose operation - it depends on the language. If you're using python and numpy it's pretty simple. But if you're looking at using C++ then you might need some libraries or pointer manipulation. But it's a fairly standard problem